# Determine whether the statement is true or false. Explain your answer.

Tags: limits

Determine whether the statement is true or false. Explain your answer.

If  $\lim_{x→a} f(x)$ exists, then so do $\lim_{x→a^−}  f(x)$ and $\lim_{x→a^+} f(x)$.

Comment: What do you think? Is it true or false?

Comment: It is frowned upon for posters to simply post their homework problem verbatim, with no indication of where it comes from, what the background is, and what their attempts at solving it have been (and where they are having trouble). In essence, you make a post in the imperative, as if we were your students and you get to order us around and tells us what to do. Guess what? You're not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We say $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$ exists when there exists a number $L \in \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $\epsilon >0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ where we have $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ whenever $0<|x-a|<\delta$.

We say $\lim_{x \to a^-} f(x)$ exists when there exists a number $L \in \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $\epsilon >0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ where we have $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ whenever $0<a-x<\delta$.

We say $\lim_{x \to a^+} f(x)$ exists when there exists a number $L \in \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $\epsilon >0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ where we have $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ whenever $0<x-a<\delta$.

I'll let you take it from here.

Comment: Ty for your help ❤(´･ω･`)?

Comment: Happy to help. In general, try to go to the definitions first when dealing with a math problem.

Comment: tysm i did it cus of your help ❤❤